# Single pipeline pointing to multi branches for a github repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to create a CI pipeline pointing to 3 different branches for a repository. I have to build solutions for a project by using the data located in three different branches under single github repo. The output of these should to go as input to the fourth branch under same pipeline. is there any option for pointing to different branches. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple branches trigger your pipeline.  Use the below syntax

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
    exclude:
    - releases/old*
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

> is there any option for pointing to different branches

For this issue , when you queue the build pipeline , you can select the branch you want to build.
[image]

If you want to create a CI pipeline,you could set the branch filters in the Triggers , the build pipeline will be triggered when any of the three different branches has a new commit.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I cant change the branch every time when I build the pipeline and I cant trigger the continuous integration as they may check the code many times. we will club all the code in one branch. How will I add the multiple agents in the pipeline to run different applications. I enable the number of agent to 5 but in I need "Agent Job(run on agent)" to be five in pipeline.

Comment: I got it how to add the multiple agents. Is it possible to point two different repo in single pipeline OR output of CI pipeline should go as input to the second pipeline. I have job which has lot of dependencies and code is split among two repos. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "Is it possible to point two different repo in single pipeline"->For this issue,I think it is not impossible in azure devops ; "output of CI pipeline should go as input to the second pipeline"->for this issue ,I think you can try to use trigger build task , for details please refer the "Build Parameters" part of this link(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have figured it out to get the data from two repository. First repo, while creating the pipeline. For second one, i have clone it using the repo downloader task. The output of CI pipeline to second pipeline- achieved using download artificats. I'm all set now.